# guacamole1.2 auth-cas raise NullPointerException

Tags: java, guacamole

I have use guacamole for three years,    begin at 0.9.13.
extensions contain "auth-jdbc-mysql" and "auth-cas"
I had an upgrade to 1.1.0 and all work right，but when I update to 1.2.0, It can't work， if I use MySQL to auth， it also works well, but use cas1.2, I get a whiteboard at login, so I check the logs, The error is as follows(from logs/localhost.2020-11-24.log),  I don't know Java, It may be very easy, help me thanks.  if I replace use cas1.1 replace cas1.2 and the others remain unchanged
it also works well

```
24-Nov-2020 01:20:32.804 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.SequenceInputStream.nextStream(SequenceInputStream.java:112)
    at java.io.SequenceInputStream.read(SequenceInputStream.java:211)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.guacamole.resource.ResourceServlet.doGet(ResourceServlet.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

When the common redirect field was implemented in 1.2.0, several components were left in the CAS module that are causing errors trying to download the app.js file when the module is enabled.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GUACAMOLE-1120